# Why are these titles grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, titles, is-it-a-sentence

I frequently come across titles that are hard for me to make sense of in grammatical terms. These titles sound like questions or incomplete sentences to me. For example:
"How Social Media Affects Young People's Attitudes" or "Why Cognitive Load Affects Decision Making"

I would like to know how and why these titles are correct. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "Why to... ..." grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67099/is-why-to-grammatical) Answer by @Jon Purdy: << It’s a headline, first of all, where some grammatical rules are different anyway. So this is not a sentence, but a noun phrase: [for example]: _(This section tells you) why to use page-level permissions._ 
That is, it tells you why you should use them. “Why to…” and “why not to…” [etc] are very common in headings to encourage or discourage the reader, respectively. It could just as well be: Reasons to use page-level permissions. >>

Comment: What ever gave you the idea that titles must be grammatical sentences? That would render most actual titles ungrammatical, like *On the Origin of Species* from Darwin, *A Tale of Two Cities* by Dickens, and the title of every single one of William Shakespeare’s plays!  No grammatical requirement exists under which titles must conform to a grammatical "sentence" (that is, a predicate expressed as a finite verb governed by a grammatical subject). So I ask again: why did you think titles were grammatical sentences?

Answer (score 0):

They are incomplete sentences. Titles don't have to be complete sentences to make sense. For example, they could even be just names of characters or objects.

What's going on grammatically though is that they are subordinate clauses and the main clause is merely understood. At its most basic form, it could be something like "This is an article" or "I discuss."

Examples from your titles:

1. [This article discusses] How Social Media Affects Young People's Attitudes
2. [I am talking about] Why Cognitive Load Affects Decision Making